# My code keep crashing with the same error (Cannot find symbol variable!)

Tags: java, android-studio, syntax-error

```
package com.example.q; 

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.app.WallpaperManager; 
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Timer; 
import java.util.TimerTask; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    
    int images[] = new int[] { R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3, } 
    Button btn; 
    int i=0; 
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn); 
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
                new Timer().schedule(new ChangeWallpaper(),0, 30000); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 

 class ChangeWallpaper extends TimerTask{ 
    @Override public void run() { 
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()); 
        try { 
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),images[i])); 
            i++;
            if(i==3){ 
                i=0; 
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
 } 
}
```

I'm having this error as mentioned in the title, originally i was facing the "R" package problem, but now it is this perhaps it could be connected ? I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling it doesn't seem to work any suggestions ?

> Cannot find symbol variable i1:17 Cannot find symbol variable i2:18
> Cannot find symbol variable i3:19

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int images[] = new int[]{R.drawable.i1,R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};
```

You just need to remove the COMMA in the end of the last item in the array.
But the question is too broad without a proper code to verify if the only answer would be this.

Comment: but when i remove the ; it says "; expected

Comment: package com.example.q;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int images[] = new int[]
            {
            R.drawable.i1,
            R.drawable.i2,
            R.drawable.i3,
    }
    Button btn;
    int i=0;
    @Override

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Timer().schedule(new ChangeWallpaper(),0, 30000);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: class ChangeWallpaper extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),images[i]));
                i++;
                if(i==3){
                    i=0;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: ive added the entire code in the comment as it was far too long to be posted as a question

Comment: If you could try to edit the post again with the full message "Error" that way would be much more easy to find the problem, you just post half the code error, and i'ts one of motives to receive downvote @PrethashaK.R